# 2 ng-option, conditional options for 2nd ng-option

Tags: angularjs

So what I am trying to do is fairly simple I think. I am pretty new though to `ng-options`. I've been using ng-repeat, in the dark about `ng-options`, but I am fairly certain `ng-options` will work better for my task.

What I am trying to do is based on the selection of whats in the first `ng-options`, will determine what the user sees in the second `ng-options`.

Here is my HTML with my best attempt at what I am trying to do:

```
<div class="formRow">
    <select name="Client" ng-model="selectedClient" ng-options="x.Name for x in clients">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="formRow">
    <select name="Profile" ng-options="x.Name for x in profiles" ng-if="x.ID = selectedClient">
    </select>
</div>
```

As you can imagine, I have 2 objects:

```
$scope.clients = [{
  Name:"ClientA",
  ID:"1"
},{
  Name:"ClientB",
  ID:"2"
}];

$scope.profiles = [{
  Name:"NORTH",
  ID:"1",
  ClientID:"1"
},{
  Name:"SOUTH",
  ID:"2",
  ClientID:"1"
},{
  Name:"EAST",
  ID:"3",
  ClientID:"2"
},{
  Name:"WEST",
  ID:"4",
  ClientID:"2"
}];
```

So, in my HTML, with the `ng-options`, what I am really trying to do logically is I want the profiles that show up in the second `ng-options` to be only whose *profiles.ClientID equals clients.ID* of the first `ng-options` that is selected.

I am not getting any errors with what I currently have going. But with that HTML, just the Clients options are being populated.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is cascading drop down list.

BTW to use ng-options directive you need to use ng-model directive as well.

You can use the built-in filter in AngularJS called *filter* in the ng-options directive to filter out the profiles based on the clients.

See the example code snippet below.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.clients = [
    { name: "ClientA", id: "1" },
    { name: "ClientB", id: "2" }
    ];

    vm.profiles = [
    { name: "NORTH", id: "1", clientId: "1" },
    { name: "SOUTH", id: "2", clientId: "1" },
    { name: "EAST", id: "3", clientId: "2" },
    { name: "WEST", id: "4", clientId: "2" }
    ];
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <div class="formRow">
      <select name="Client" ng-model="ctrl.selectedClient" ng-options="x.name for x in ctrl.clients">
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="formRow">
      <select name="Profile" ng-model="ctrl.selectedProfile" ng-options="x.name for x in ctrl.profiles | filter: { clientId: ctrl.selectedClient.id }">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```